# Sinc Based Multi Dimension Signal Resampling on the Fourier Spectrum (DFT)

Tags: matlab, dft, interpolation, frequency-domain, resampling

As a generalization of the following questions:

- [The Proper Way to Do Sinc Downsampling (DFT Downsampling) for Uniformly Sampled Discrete Signals with Finite Number of Samples](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/72433/the-proper-way-to-do-sinc-downsampling-dft-downsampling-for-uniformly-sampled).
- [The Proper Way to Do Sinc Upsampling (DFT Upsampling) for Uniformly Sampled Discrete Signals with Finite Number of Samples](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/79356/the-proper-way-to-do-sinc-upsampling-dft-upsampling-for-uniformly-sampled-disc).
- [Applying 2D Sinc Interpolation for Upsampling in the Fourier Domain (DFT / FFT)](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/81493/applying-2d-sinc-interpolation-for-upsampling-in-the-fourier-domain-dft-fft).
- [Applying 2D Sinc Interpolation for Downsampling in the Fourier Domain (DFT / FFT)](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/81529/applying-2d-sinc-interpolation-for-downsampling-in-the-fourier-domain-dft-fft).

I would like to know how to handle the `n` dimensional general case both for Upsampling and Downsampling.
The above questions deals with 1D and 2D and I wonder how to handle the general `nD` case.
The answer should be practical, namely emphasize implementation considerations.

Comment: the same; the thing you want is inherently a separable kernel, so you can fist 1-D interpolate in one, then in the other dimension.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, It's a bit trickier in high dimensions. As the slice is `N - 1` which requires a delicate handling.

Comment: @Royi interesting! Reading up on this :)

Answer (score 1):

The general $ n $ dimension case can be solved with the following loop:

```
for dimIdx in 1:ndims(tX)
    tXDft = fft(tX, dimIdx);
    tXDft = PadOrCrop(tXDft, dimIdx);
    tXDft = FixSlice(tXDft, dimIdx)
    tX    = ifft(tXDft, dimIdx);
end
```

The tricky parts are handling the cropping (Downsampling) or padding (Upsampling) for the $ n - 1 $ dimensions slice.

One way to solve it is to recursively work on smaller dimensions slices until we get to 1D / 2D slice which is solved in the questions you linked to.

Another way is to define a slice indexing.
Assume the array has indices of: `(1:5, 1:10, 1:15, 1:20)` then the the $ i $ -th slice in the $ d $ -th dimensions has the indices, for `i = 4` and `d = 2` (1:5, 4, 1:15, 1:20).

Those slices are the elements we can treat as scalars in the 1D case. Namely split them or add them in order to compensate for Upsampling / Downsampling.

So basically we do, 1D DFT, then we apply cropping / padding according to need at the dimension in work, then we extract the slices at the bin which needs to be fixed and add them / split them then Inverse DFT.

Comment: Please elaborate on the implementation.