# Generate an Ideal 2D Low Pass Filter in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab, frequency-spectrum, lowpass-filter, frequency-domain

I've been tasked with creating a 32 x 32 half-band low-pass image filter in MATLAB. My thinking is to generate the ideal filter mask in the frequency domain and compute the corresponding convolution mask using the inverse FFT. I first generate the filter in the frequency domain.

```
filter = zeros(32);
filter (1:8, 1:8) = 1;
filter (1:8, 24:32) = 1;
filter (24:32, 1:8) = 1;
filter (24:32, 24:32) = 1;
```

This filter turns out to be the following in the frequency domain. I've confirmed my MATLAB code produces this pattern which is symmetric.
[image]

Note, I'm assuming I need to define the mask with the frequency ranges from 0 -> 2pi rad/sec, hence putting the "ones" in the corners.

I then generate the convolution mask using the "iift2" MATLAB function. However, this mask turns out to be complex which raises some red flags. I would expect it to be a real filter.

```
mask = ifft2(filter)
```

When I convolve this filter mask with my image however, I get some weird artifacts.

```
image_filtered = imfilter(image_orig, mask);
```

[image]

I'm curious if there is some flaw in my thinking here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it a bad idea to filter by zeroing out FFT bins?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-filter-by-zeroing-out-fft-bins)

Comment: all the things said for 1D filters there 100% directly translate to 2D filters, plus you forgot the circular nature of DFT convolution.

Comment: also "ideal low-pass filter" has a specific meaning, and that is a low-pass filter with infinitely steep transition, which would be infinite in size and hence can not be implemented.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm more interested in whether or not the fourier mask I've defined is correct and why I would be getting a complex convolution mask when performing the IFFT. Ideally, I would like the IFFT to create a 2D signal that entirely real.

Comment: again, no, you didn't define that mask correctly for any practical filtering problem.

Comment: plus, your mask is asymmetric far as I can tell, so the IDFT of the same not being real is expected?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Here is the shifted frequency domain signal I've generate which should be symmetric: https://imgur.com/a/E7hxlZP Would this not be an ideal low-pass filter frequency spectrum?

Comment: "Why is this not ideal?": see the answer I've linked to. The code you post doesn't seem to be what generates that image. You have an off-by-one error in your code.

Comment: I understand that sampling an ideal frequency domain will not produce an ideal filter after an IFFT due to spectral smearing etc. However, I should still get a filter mask that is at least a low-pass filter if not ideal. I'm starting to think my problem is that i assumed an ideal 2D low-pass filter is "square" shaped, but it's actually circular.

Comment: no, that's not it. You seemingly haven't really understood what happens

Comment: Isn't what I'm describing just the "Window Design Method"? I window the ideal filter response and take the inverse FFT? How am I incorrect in this line of thinking?

Comment: exactly, you forgot to window your ideal function. And your code still produces an asymmetric function, too.

Answer (score 1):

First, I will replace some of the coefficients with `0.5` and `0.25`.
In order to understand this, please have a look at:

- [The Proper Way to Do Sinc Upsampling (DFT Upsampling) for Uniformly Sampled Discrete Signals with Finite Number of Samples](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/79356).
- [The Proper Way to Do Sinc Downsampling (DFT Downsampling) for Uniformly Sampled Discrete Signals with Finite Number of Samples](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/72433).

In order to keep the symmetry in place, what you need to have (I will show in `16x16` filter, but it is the same):

[image]

The reason to the `0.5` value is above. The reason for the `0.25` values is the separability property of the DFT, basically multiplying `0.5 * 0.5`.

In order to verify it, the trick is to apply `fftshift()`. We expect to see a symmetric centered filter.

[image]

The center is at `7` and indeed around it we see a symmetric filter as required.

The inverse DFT, using `ifft2()` will generate the time filter, yet in coordinate system which starts at `(0, 0)`:

[image]

Applying the `fftshift()` will show use the filter as we want.

[image]

Indeed looks like a 2D Sinc / Dirichlet Kernel.

If you calculate the maximum imaginary element of the inverse DFT you will see it is within the numerical error of the calculation, so basically zero as expected.

**Remark**: This is not a good way to generate filters. You better build a 1D filters according to the needs of each axis and then use outer product to generate the 2D filter.